# Options for remote desktop with single session and hide local screen in 2021?

Tags: 20.04, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, i3-wm

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop at work which I need to remote into. I'm able to with xrdp, but there's a problem:

Every time I remote in it creates a new session, and when I sign in locally that session dies. I want to be able to use the same session every time, like remoting into Windows does.

Now, you might be thinking, oh, why don't you use VNC then?

I want my local screen locked when I've remoted in. I don't want people walking by to see what I'm doing and be able to access my computer.

I've scoured the web and haven't found any solutions to the problem. I've found ways to remote into the same session every time, which is a fair compromise, but haven't gotten that working yet. Another caveat is that I use i3wm/regolith, and would prefer to not switch to xfce when remoting.

**Is there any way to lock the remote screen when VNCing (beyond turning off the monitors)?**

**Is there a way for to connect and share the same session using RPD?**

**Any other solutions to this seemingly common problem?**

Comment: The answer to your questions one and two seems to be both "No". As you have found there are other solutions. I prefer AnyDesk. It is lighter than TeamViewer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
TeamViewer has the option to disable local input and black the remote screen!